storing login credentials, mySQL or IPFS
hi im very new to developing, total newbie here and im on my final year project on blockchain development. i want to ask if for creating a login session we must store the credentials (username & password) somewhere right? where should i store the credentials, mySQL or IPFS

The credentials like passwords should never be stored in databases directly as plain texts. You've to encrypt or hash them using some JS library like bcrypt, as shown in this tutorial. After encryption, you can store them wherever you want, depending on how you're mapping the credentials with the corresponding users.
Like in centralised databases, the mapping is direct as the user details including username, password (hashed), etc. are all stored as a single model in a collection (in case of a non-relational database like MongoDB) or in a table (in case of a relational database like SQL).
If you want to add a decentralised touch to it, then you can store the hashed passwords onto IPFS, and store the corresponding cids (content-identifier) in the database record corresponding to the users.
Or, if you would like to hash it directly using SQL while storing, then you can refer to this tutorial.

thank you! very helpful info

If theres address involved, you can use address, and store it paired with username even in open database. So no need for password in web3.
Just require a message sign from wallet, as part of authentication process, and validate the message on server side.

is it fine if i dont use wallet for authentication? just basic php login to authenticate user. or is it mandatory

of course, you can use anything suitable for your needs
